# Suppressing Compiler Warning C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm getting a compile-time error.  It complains that I'm initializing a variable, but not referencing it.  What's happening is that I initialize it then make a debug print statement that only get's compiled in for a debug build but not a release build.  The error in question is warning c4189 (it's treated as an error and won't compile).

Is it possible to suppress this warning?  How about warnings in general?

Comment: You shall try to understand the warning and make warning free code instead of suppressing it.

Comment: Why not put the variable declaration inside the debug-only part as well?

Comment: If you really want to, there's a `#pragma` to 'fix' warnings.  On the whole, though, you should fix the code, not use the `#pragma`.

Comment: You can just click on the warnings tab (if you're using mvs) to hide the warnings. It should still compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't suppress the warning, fix it! Wrap the declaration and initialization of the variable so it only exists in a debug build too.

Comment: The value IS INITIALIZED but never referenced in debug since the referencing code is stripped out in a release build.

Comment: @CPlayer you are correct, I edited my answer to give the correct solution in that case.